# Autocomplete feature not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
<title>Welcome to the page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script> 
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="suggestion" />
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON( "data.json", function( data ) {
      
      var data_arr = data.map(function(val){
                 return val.name;
        })
       
       auto(data_arr)
     });
         
    function auto(data_arr){

        $('#suggestion').autocomplete({
            source: data_arr    
        }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderMenu = function (ul, items) {
            var that = this;
            var val = that.element.val();
            $.each($.grep(items, function (value, key) {
                return new RegExp(val.toLowerCase()).test(value.value.toLowerCase().slice(0, val.length))
            }), function (index, item) {
                that._renderItemData(ul, item);
            });
        };
    }
    
</script>
</html>
```

Data.json

```
[  
        {
            "id": "136599",
            "name": "CE712A#BGJ"
        },
        {
            "id": "137704",
            "name": "12C#ABA"
        },
        {
            "id": "137705",
            "name": "F2212A#ABA"
        }
]
```

The above code works for desired values which are present in the `data.json` file. Once any value other then the `data.json` file is entered, the suggestion pops out a bit and vanishes. I actually want nothing no be shown when the input is not present in `data.json`. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="suggestion" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#suggestion').autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp) {
      $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
        var data_arr = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(data.map(function(val) {
          return val.name;
        }), req.term);
        resp(data_arr);
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

If you use a Function for Source, you can adjust the results of a JSON output before passing them to Autocomplete. You might consider mapping them to `label` and `value` pairs if needed.

See More: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @Beginner it is already in "actual code" yet I cannot test with an AJAX call. You will have to update and adapt your code for testing.

Comment: This is the error I am getting:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined
    at jquery-ui.js:7143
    at Function.grep (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.filter (jquery-ui.js:7142)
    at Object.success ((index):16)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4)